# Создание календаря на js. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать календарь на js. Есть таблица 7x7, включая строку заголовков дней недели. Заполнение таблицы происходит корректно. По клику на ячейку должна выводиться полная дата нажатой ячейки. Насколько я понимаю, при назначении ячейке определенной даты, эта дата должна записываться в двумерный массив.

Код с похожей проблемой:

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      
  funcs[i] = function() {          
    console.log("My value: " + i); 
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                     
}
```

Мой случай:

```
var dates = new Array(7);    //объявление двумерного массива для дат
for(var m=0; m<7; m++)
{
    dates[m]=new Array();
}

function record(date) {
    return function () {
        alert('выбрана дата: '+date);
    };
}

calendarFill();

function calendarFill(){
    var today = new Date();
    var local_date = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);  //1е число текущего месяца
    var week_day = local_date.getDay();
    var i;  //определяет с какой строчки надо заполнять дни текущего месяца
    var j;  //определяет с какого столбца надо заполнять дни текущего месяца
    var k;  //определяет с какого столбца надо заполнять дни предыдущего месяца

    if(week_day==1){//если день недели 1го числа текущего месяца - понедельник, то оно записывается во 2ой строчке, во всех остальных случаях в 1ой строчке
        i=2;
        j=week_day-1;
        k=6;
    }
    if(week_day==0){//если день недели 1го числа - воскресение
        i=1;
        j=6;
        k=5;
    }
    else{
        i=1;
        j=week_day-1;
        k=week_day-2;
    }

    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr'); 
    for(i; i<7; i++ ){
        var columns = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
        for(j; j<7; j++){
            columns[j].innerHTML = local_date.getDate().toString();
            columns[j] = record(local_date);
            columns[j].onclick = function () { 
                dates[i][j]();
            }
            local_date.setDate(local_date.getDate()+1);
        }
        j=0;
    }

    var local_date = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);

    var columns = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(k; k>=0; k--){
        local_date.setDate(local_date.getDate()-1);
        console.log(local_date);
        columns[k] = record(local_date);
        columns[k].onclick = function() {
            dates[1][k]();
        }
        columns[k].innerHTML = local_date.getDate().toString();
    }
}
```

**Traceback:** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Как привести код в рабочее состояние?

**EDIT1:** Ошибка в строке:

```
dates[i][j]();
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript так устроен, что вы не можете просто написать:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 100);
}
```

По той причине, что значение переменной `var` в момент времени через 100 мс будет равно последнему значению, которое ей присваивали - и это будет 10.

Это распространенная ошибка, которую допускают те, кто не очень хорошо знаком с тем, как работает `var`: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676362/javascript-variable-binding-and-loop).

Все дело в том, что для `var` на каждой итерации цикла не создается новая переменная, а переиспользуется старая. Чтобы избежать подобной ошибки, есть два выхода:

1. Использовать `let` вместо `var`. `let` - относительно новая фича языка, она может не поддерживаться старыми браузерами. Поэтому данный вариант следует использовать с осторожностью. Пример кода:

   ```js
   for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
     setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(i);
     }, 100);
   }
   ```
2. Второй вариант - создать новую область видимости с локальной для нее переменной, к примеру - обернуть тело цикла в анонимную функцию и вызвать ее с аргументом:

   ```js
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
     (function(i) {
         setTimeout(function() {
             console.log(i);
         }, 100);
     })(i);
   }
   ```

Учитывая данные знания, вы сможете переписать ваш код, чтобы он вел себя правильно (нужно исправить и остальные подобные моменты):

```
for(i; i<7; i++ ){
    var columns = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(j; j<7; j++){
        columns[j].innerHTML = local_date.getDate().toString();
        columns[j] = record(local_date);

        // Вот тут вот обернем создание callback'а в анонимную функцию
        (function(i, j) {
            columns[j].onclick = function () { 
                dates[i][j]();
            }
        })(i, j);

        local_date.setDate(local_date.getDate()+1);
    }
    j=0;
}
```

Comment: dates[i][j] is not a function
    at HTMLTableCellElement.columns.(anonymous function).onclick